# Pandas reshape Dataframe based on column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe `df = pd.Dataframe({'year':[2001,2002,2001,2002,2003],'1':[36984,36559,12927,12414,9731],'2':[28384，33467，11677，11258，8407],'State':["Alabama","Alabama","Alaska","Alaska","Alaska"]})` like this:

```
year    1         2      State
2001    36984   28384   Alabama
2002    36559   33467   Alabama
2001    12927   11677   Alaska
2002    12414   11258   Alaska
2003    9731    8407    Alaska
```

. Now I want to organize this `df` to one column group by `State`, like this:

```
year-month  Alabama Alaska
2001-1      36984   12927
2001-2      28384   11677
2002-1      36559   12414
2002-2      33467   11258   
2003-1      NaN     9371
2003-2      NaN     8407
```

How to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with join columns and then [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = df.melt(['year','State'])
df1['year-month'] = df1['year'].astype(str) + '-' + df1['variable'].astype(str)

df1 = df1.pivot('year-month','State','value')
print (df1)
State       Alabama   Alaska
year-month                  
2001-1      36984.0  12927.0
2001-2      28384.0  11677.0
2002-1      36559.0  12414.0
2002-2      33467.0  11258.0
2003-1          NaN   9731.0
2003-2          NaN   8407.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
out=(df.groupby(['State','year'])
       .first()
        .unstack(1)
        .swaplevel(axis=1)
        .T
        .rename_axis(columns='year-month'))
out.index=out.index.map(lambda x:'-'.join(map(str,x)))
```

output of `out`:

```
year-month  Alabama     Alaska
2001-1      36984.0     12927.0
2002-1      36559.0     12414.0
2003-1      NaN         9731.0
2001-2      28384.0     11677.0
2002-2      33467.0     11258.0
2003-2      NaN         8407.0
```

Comment: @jezrael Nope Sir Not sure that If it maintains the perfromace on large data so....removed...tried via timeit

Comment: Be free add more data and then it is good idea. But testing  in 5 rows of data is contraproductive (because in large data should be times different)